# How can I convert a struct or JSON into a raw string?

Tags: string, struct, rust, hyper

I have tests and  I need to send JSON data to my server. I have the following test:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use std::io::Read;
use hyper::*;

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct LegacyJsonRequest {
    jsonrpc: String,
    method: String,
    params: String,
    id: i32,
    auth: String,
}

#[test]
fn apiinfo_jsonrpc_tests() {
    let client = Client::new();

    let url = "http://localhost:6767/api_jsonrpc.php";

    let mut http_reader = header::Headers::new();
    http_reader.set_raw("Content-Type", vec![b"application/json".to_vec()]);

    //TODO: How to use a struct and 'export' it to a raw string literal???
    let request_data = LegacyJsonRequest {
        jsonrpc: "2.0".to_string(),
        method: "apiinfo.version".to_string(),
        params: "[]".to_string(),
        auth: "[]".to_string(),
        id: 1,
    };

    let encoded_request = rustc_serialize::json::encode(&request_data).unwrap();

    let mut response = client.post(url)
        .body(encoded_request)
        .send()
        .unwrap();

}
```

With this code, the following error is returned:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper::client::Body<'_>: std::convert::From<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
```

If I **drop the struct and JSON encoded code and create a simple raw string literal** and reference it on the body method, it works. Example:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use std::io::Read;
use hyper::*;

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct LegacyJsonRequest {
    jsonrpc: String,
    method: String,
    params: String,
    id: i32,
    auth: String,
}

#[test]
fn apiinfo_jsonrpc_tests() {
    let client = Client::new();

    let url = "http://localhost:6767/api_jsonrpc.php";

    let mut http_reader = header::Headers::new();
    http_reader.set_raw("Content-Type", vec![b"application/json".to_vec()]);

    let request_data =
        r#"{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "apiinfo.version", "params": {}, "auth": {}, "id": "1"}"#;

    let mut response = client.post(url)
        .body(request_data)
        .send()
        .unwrap();

}
```

So: How can I convert my struct or JSON into a **raw string**?

I Know that the error E0277 is about the implementation of a trait for the "Hyper::client::Body<'_>", but look, this is not the question; the question is: how to convert a struct or JSON into a raw string, nothing more. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you do further research on what that error message means.

Comment: I just added more complete examples. If I can convert the JSON or Struct object into a raw string then I dont need to implement a trait for hyper::client::Body<'_>. The question is about the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

> I Know that the error E0277 is about the implementation of a trait for the "Hyper::client::Body<'_>", but look, this is not the question; the question is: how to convert a struct or JSON into a raw string, nothing more.

It is 100% **impossible** to convert to a raw string.

You see, "raw strings" **don't exist once the source code has been parsed** — they are only a conceit of the source code. There's no way to convert *anything* into a raw string because it doesn't exist to be converted *to*.

All that exists are string slices (`&str`) and owned strings (`String`).

This solves OP's question, nothing more, as requested. Anyone interested in the solution to the underlying problem is welcome to continue reading.

---

Checking the [documentation for `RequestBuilder::body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.10.4/hyper/client/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.body), you can see that it accepts any type that can be converted into a `Body`:

```
impl<'a> RequestBuilder<'a> {
    fn body<B: Into<Body<'a>>>(self, body: B) -> RequestBuilder<'a>;
}
```

If you then review the [documentation for `Body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.10.4/hyper/client/enum.Body.html), you will see what implementations of `From` exist for it:

```
impl<'a, R: Read> From<&'a mut R> for Body<'a> {
    fn from(r: &'a mut R) -> Body<'a>;
}
```

Coupled with the knowledge that [`From` implies `Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html), you know that you can pass anything that implements `Read` to `body`. Actually, the **compiler tells you this in the error message**:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper::client::Body<'_>: std::convert::From<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:37:10
   |
37 |         .body(encoded_request)
   |          ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `hyper::client::Body<'_>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <hyper::client::Body<'a> as std::convert::From<&'a mut R>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<hyper::client::Body<'_>>` for `std::string::String`
```

This is the problem - there's actually *more* ways of converting to a `Body`, and the documentation doesn't show them<sup>1</sup>! Checking out [the source](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/v0.10.4/src/client/mod.rs#L414-L426), you can see:

```
impl<'a> Into<Body<'a>> for &'a str {
    #[inline]
    fn into(self) -> Body<'a> {
        self.as_bytes().into()
    }
}

impl<'a> Into<Body<'a>> for &'a String {
    #[inline]
    fn into(self) -> Body<'a> {
        self.as_bytes().into()
    }
}
```

This means that you can pass in a reference to the string, which will then be converted to a `Body`, just like [vitalyd guessed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42352956/155423):

```
let mut response = client.post(url)
    .body(&encoded_request)
    .send()
    .unwrap();
```

---

**1** I'm going to look to see if this is a filed issue already or not, cause this sure seems incorrect.

Comment: Amazing answer. I'll try this tonight. Until now, for me, Rust doesnt have a high learning curve; instead it solves problems in a simples way that forces us to think of the New possibilities.